# mvc 3 - Automatically going to HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-post, actionmethod

I have an action as follows:

```
    public ActionResult ChangeFeeCheck(string id)
    {

       ViewBag.id = id;
       return View();
    }
```

on my View, I have the following:

```
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "CreateList";
     }



     Please enter first name <br /><br />


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

    @Html.Textbox("firstname")

    <input type="button" id="SaveChanges" value="Save" />  
    }
```

When I click on the button, I was expecting it to to the following

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeFeeCheck(string firstname)
    {
      .....

    }
```

I am not sure when MVC will automatically go to the HttpPost or if I when need to manually have it there. In the above, it does not go there directly. I have to use the

```
    window.location.href
```

and pass the url of the controller/action.

Meaning, isn't the default for

```
    Html.BeginForm()
```

The HttpPost(same name as the HttpGet)

Comment: @SLaks. The problem is with the type of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following "Convention over configuration" rule over here, then the view you have created here must be for `ChangeFeeCheck` action, and `ChangeFeeCheck` here looks like will make compiler confused as no overload,  same name, same signatures.

and then when method for form is get it would go to the first one, while if method for form is POST, it will call the one decorated with `[HttpPost]`

And because you are using submit button and by default HTML form generated uses POST action, it call the `[HttpPost]`

You can refer this article (from the internet archive as original link is now down): https://web.archive.org/web/20120527133344/http://microsoftmentalist.com:80/2011/09/07/asp-net-mvc-difference-between-httpget-and-httppost-with-example/

See for example how `GET` and `POST` action methods are overloaded.

Comment: problem is that he doesnt have a submit button.

Answer (score 3):

You need the button to be a `submit` button:

Change:

```
<input type="button" id="SaveChanges" value="Save" />  
             ^^^^^^
```

To:

```
<input type="submit" id="SaveChanges" value="Save" />  
             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. I initially tried it with submit like you menitoned and that did not work. I then went with the button and then in jquery put the window.location.href. I will try it again though. Also with the way I am doing it, with button, is window.location.href the only way to go to a controller/action. I have tried it with .$post before but it goes to the controller/action and then back to the jquery script

Comment: location.href will issue a GET and you wont get any of your form data.  If you want to submit with javascript, you need to call a submit() method on the form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all same signature same name method can't be compiled in same controller it will give you the compilation error already have member of same parameter type.

You have to differentiate these two similar name method by different signature.

Regarding HttpPost and HttpGet your get method will be called whenever you have to retrive data or your page load is called for that view.

HttpPost method will be called either you are using button of type submit or your input type is button but using jquery you are giving ajax call on button click and your ajax type is "Post"
$.ajax({
url: "Action"
type: "Post"
},succees: function(){alert('succeed');});